Are these Avid BB7 Brake Pads metal or organic?
I have Avid BB7 mechanical brakes.
I would like to know if the pads on my bicycle are metal (or is it called sintered) or organic (rubber?).
I compared the pads on the bicycle to unused metal pads. They look the same. I scratched both used and unused with a screw driver. Feels the same. Also scratched with a finger nail feels the same.
In the pictures below the top pair are the unused metal pads. Below that are the front and rear pairs that I am unsure about. There are 2 pictures because of the flash light position.


Do the numbers on the back of the pads mean anything?

Top unused pair: 70
Bottom used pairs:
1M025 or 1H025
1M038 or 1H038
2A172
2A180
I assume metal pads can only be used with certain rotors (i.e. the metal of the rotor must be harder than the pads). The rotors are

Front: SRAM 160mm Center Lock, TC12JUL19, Min thickness 1.55mm
Rear: Rohloff 160 mm compatible to Shimano, Hayes, Formula, Avid, EAN Code
4250307402342 Article number 8281, 1.5mm thickness




All SRAM and Avid rotors that I have encountered are ok with metal sintered pads. Metal sintered pads are standard equipment with several caliper models in the range so the rotors offered have to be capable.
As far as I am aware, it is only shimano that offer rubbish soft rotors that limit your pad choice, though other budget brands might too.

On the SRAM website, it seems that the brake pads with the copper backing are sintered. There is no need to examine the pad itself.

Available Pad Compounds
Each pad compound will have a different colored backing plate. This makes identification easier for riders. The table below will assist in your selection[…]



Compound
Color
Use




Sintered
Copper
Heavy Duty


Organic
Black
Quiet


Organic
Grey
Powerful


Organic / Lightweight
Aluminum
Quiet / Light




Here a screenshot. (The page also mentions the Avid BB7 pads.)

